# Azure Pipeline if exists function

Tags: azure, yaml, devops, pipeline

Question:
Does Azure DevOps Pipeline have any sort of ifExist function to check if the branch exists in the Azure repository? - I want to check if the branch exists first before checking out the default branch, this is currently what I have,

```
parameters:
- name: branch
  default: main
  type: object

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: esign_new_svc
    type: git
    name: InternalProjects/esign_new_svc
    ref: ${{ parameters.branch }}
```

but if I put an inexistent branch, I see a pipeline failure with the error "sorry the branch doesn't exist"... I know that branch doesn't exist, but I don't want the pipeline to fail, I want to check out the default branch if given branch in parameters doesn't exist, simple as is.

Thanks